# AWS CloudFront caching contents forever?

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to cache images stored in S3 in Tokyo region to an edge in Korea.

So here's my question.

Say I have many images in S3 and I would like all of them to be cached in the Korea edge. Also, I would like all those cached images to live forever(TTL=forever) unless I update or delete one of them. (You could say replicate S3 in Korea edge)

I would really like to do this because my service is deployed only in Korea for the time being.

> In short, is it possible to cache a lot of contents(like 4~500,000 images) with TTL=forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can use the `Cache-Control` headers to specify a very high expiration time (maximum is in the year 2038), it will not guarantee that CloudFront will actually cache the files for that long.

As any caching proxy or CDN, each CloudFront location has a limited amount of disk space to use for caching and it would not be feasible to store files that have a very low number of hits for a long time. The amount of time that CloudFront will actually cache a file is completely up to them and you should not rely on this (e.g. remove the source files in the hopes that the edge location will still have a copy).

Answer (score 1):

Set this header in S3 and CloudFront will use it to cache assets.

e.g.

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
```

And the max is 100 years.

> The maximum value is 100 years.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html

Using 100 years in seconds:

```
100*365*24*60*60
```

e.g.

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3153600000
```